# EntityFrameworkCore MySql error in DotnetCore2.0 webapi

Tags: mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I Am working with EntityFrameworkCore MySql on a dotnetcore 2.0 api .

Here is the error I am getting

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ConcreteTypeMapping' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping'.
```

I have been getting this error when trying to access any DbSet.  I cannot track down if it is a mapping issue, connection issue or library issue.  If anyone has seen this please let me know.  Otherwise here is what I have so far.

```
public class GamerDbContext : DbContext
{
    public GamerDbContext()
    {

    }

    public GamerDbContext(DbContextOptions<GamerDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GamerModel>();
    }

    public DbSet<GamerModel> GamerModel { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<GamerProfileModel> GamerProfiles { get; set; }
}

public class GamerModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    //[StringLength(36)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    //[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    //[StringLength(1024)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    //[NotMapped]
    //public List<GamerProfileModel> GamerProfiles { get; set; }
}
-- auto-generated definition
CREATE TABLE Gamers
(
   Id       INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Username VARCHAR(36)   NOT NULL,
   Password VARCHAR(1024) NULL,
   CONSTRAINT Gamers_Id_uindex
   UNIQUE (Id),
   CONSTRAINT Gamers_Username_uindex
   UNIQUE (Username)
);
```

Comment: Can you post Code how you are accessing DbSet?

Comment: Cool, you can raise issue in Entity Framework Core repository in GitHub. So that they can fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out.

It turns out I was referencing the nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version 2.1.0-preview2-final. It seems that there is a compatibility issue with that and MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore. Once I removed the first package it worked fine.